# Стили страниц вставляемых на сайт через iFrame

Tags: html, css, iframe

Люди, подскажите новичку. Если через iframe что-то вставляется со сторонних сайтов, мы можем там внешний вид настроить? Через css, например?

Для примера. [Тут](http://etnoteatr.ru/) - как фон у вконтакте поменять на черный, например.

Answer (score 3):

Только используя **jQuery**. Но как по мне - это изврат! Что такое **jQuery** почитать можно в интернете.

Как реализовать?

```
Допустим задаем фрейму id "frame"
Допустим внутри фрейма есть id "if"
И допустим jQuery
$('#frame').contents().find('#if').css('имя', 'значение');
```

Comment: Интересно.. В моем недавнем вопросе на эту же тематику мне ответили, что ковыряться в недрах iframe не получится. Надо будет проверить Ваш вариант!